# How to make the icon background of an Android app transparent?

Tags: java, android, xml, image, android-studio

A PNG image is to be used as the icon foreground, and the background should be completely transparent.

Using `Android Studio > New Image Asset > Configure Image Asset dialog` in the Asset Studio, virtually very combination of options for the background has been tried, including removing the file entirely from the path and deleting the background tags in `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml`.

Removing the file from the path in this wizard and removing the tags from the XML files almost does the trick, but a faint black outline remains as the background (~alpha=20%). All other options for the Background Layer leave either a stark white or black background behind the foreground image when viewing the icon on the device's launcher.

Many apps manage to have a foreground only on their icons, so it is possible. What am I doing wrong here?

Update: Thank you for the quick comments! I tried both the solutions provided as answers, same result. Screen capture is uploaded as suggested.

Updating just the Legacy icon in the wizard is not sufficient, as that only changes the Legacy icon format. The newer "Adaptive" icons are required as well. Even if the background is set to a completely transparent square png, Android Studio changes it to white. If the background file is removed entirely, the wizard allows completion, but then Android Studio uses a slightly opaque black background, as shown. With respect to the uploaded image, there should be nothing behind the foreground, completely gray to in this case without any visible circle.

[Screen capture from device running API 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b5ni.png)

Comment: can you show an image of what you're getting and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: if you want to use transparent icon for ic_launcher, then paste your 512x512 size icon to drawable, you don't need to import it through -new image asset > configure... just pasting does the job. and then refer to the newly pasted icon in manifest

Comment: (If you wish to enquire about downvotes, please do it in the comments. It is not of interest to most people, who do not sign in or vote. Most calls for explanation of votes go unnoticed by the voter(s) anyway, so I'd suggest you just ignore it.)

Comment: @halfer I'll follow your lead here, since it's my first post I'll attempt to solicit an explanation for the downvote via the comments.

Comment: @halfer It would be nice to have some idea of what was wrong in the post, otherwise I am left with an empty reprimand and no ability to improve.

Comment: Sure, in the comments is fine. You'll find that occasionally you'll get inexplicable DVs, but if you use the site over the long term and your contributions are good, your work will get more upvotes than down. I'd only try to figure it out if I received very heavy downvoting. You can always discuss it on the _Meta_ site too, but for single DVs, the answer will be "we don't know" `:-)`.

Comment: My subjective and untested opinion about boilerplate material in questions that insists "I've been at this for hours", "I really have researched this" (etc) is that it attracts downvotes. I've written about [language confidence here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).

Comment: @halfer Wow, your language confidence article is extensive and heavily commented. I need a moment to absorb the level of interest and opinions about forum post etiquette! My next question will not be prefaced with any indication of the blood, sweat, and tears on my keyboard. ;)

Comment: Yeah, the core community here is _really_ committed to getting the teaching/effort/quality mix right. It's a hard balance, and of course we can't avoid taking human psychology into account when examining these issues. That said, we can't know that this was the reason for a single DV in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method 1:**

if you have a png, just copy it and paste it in drawable, and refer to image name from manifest (be careful to change both the *android:icon* and *android:roundIcon* attributes).

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/new_image"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/new_image"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        ....
        </application>
```

**Method 2:**

**Goto file > new > image asset**, make sure you select a png image (with transparent background) & set background shape to none.

[image]

Comment: The solution that worked for me was to implement both of these methods simultaneously.

Comment: thank you very very very much @AmirDe, upvoted for saving my day with Method 1.

Answer (score 2):

First you have a background image to get transparent icon without any background image you can't get your icon transparent .

And if you look to get image transparent you simply use some photo editor.

Answer (score 0):

*Get a view of the imageButton*

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.myImageBtn);
```

*get the icon from the app for example Chrome*

```
pkgnam="com.android.chrome";
Intent intent1 = ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pgknam);
Drawable myIcon = getPackageManager().getActivityIcon(intent1);
```

*set the background icon the same as the foreground icon*

```
v.setForeground(myIcon);
v.setBackground(myIcon);
```

Comment: Context ctx;      
    ctx = this;