# How to Remove white Background from icon?

Tags: android

I have an app on android that create home shortcut icon.
The image of the icon is image that i set programmatically from the drawable

[image]
Now the problem is, when the shortcut was created on the home screen it's created with white background.

How do i remove that white backgroubd and set image to full size of icon?

Thank you all..

**EDIT: the app i was talking about is app that i developed using android studio and just want to set full size of image when i create home shortcut**

Comment: I just update my post

Comment: I think It helps you to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960640/how-to-make-the-icon-background-of-an-android-app-transparent

Answer (score 2):

This is highly dependent on the launcher you use. The image looks like the standard google android 8+ (?) icon shape.
I theory it could be part of the icon you created but since you are asking this I doubt it.

In older versions of android the outer shape of the icons were individual, while rather cool and the outline correctly shown while dragging them etc many complained about the lack of a uniform look of all the icons in the app drawer etc.

It was introduced to make all icons seem more uniform.
Long pressing an empty space in the Google Pixel launcher for example shows a choice to go into the settings for the launcher and there you can change the shape all icons should have:

[image: Icon shape settings in the Home settings]

In addition to this, apps can take advantage of the various shapes and adapt to them and fill them out so to speak. See for example the Chrome icon while changing the icon shapes in the launcher settings.

Introduced in android 8: The feature is called adaptive icons.

See the docs about adaptive icons here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

Answer (score 0):

That is because of adaptive icons -  a feature of Android 8 and can't or shouldn't be changed.  You can at best change the colour of the background.

Comment: Ok, but, for example: the icon of Whatsapp is without white background and some other apps has white backgrounds(as my app). How can i set my app's icon in android studio to be without white background

Comment: I just found out that my redmi and xiaomi phones (and yes, most lauchers) have icon packs, so depending on the theme of the phone (mine had ART+ Icons enabled) a small group of icons will be given this special treatment. When I disabled the icon packs, the background of those app icons returned (green for whatsapp, white for messenger)

Answer (score 0):

i removed the white background from the launcher icon by following these guidelines https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio

a few more points

1. in the background layer, move the slider to resize the icon until you see no what would have been the white background.
2. in the manifest file, change the icons to reference the mipmap folder;

   android:icon="@mipmap/yourlogo"
   android:roundIcon="@mipmap/yourlogo[image: configure background layer in Asset Studio]"