# Black background the app icons Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I need an app icon with a transparent background, but for some reason, the background is black at `Full Bleed Layers`. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[Screenshot of Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBVCc.png)

This is not a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960640/how-to-make-the-icon-background-of-an-android-app-transparent)!

Comment: `Full bleed layers` will always have a backround.

Comment: Also, you can't say that there is no answer to your question as you have no way of knowing.

Comment: You can simply select **Launcher Icons(Legacy Only)**..to avoid this